# What is Stack Overflow Labs? Why is it sponsoring GenAI SE?

Tags: discussion, company, stack-overflow-labs

I recently noticed a new webpage: https://stackoverflow.co/labs/

[image]

What's the purpose of this new webpage? When was this created? Was there any staff announcement about this webpage?

---

I just got to know that [Stack Overflow Labs is sponsoring](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/80) [GenAI Stack Exchange site](https://genai.stackexchange.com/). If it's supposed to be a "central hub to share our experiments, demos, insights, and news", why is it sponsoring the site? Is the income generated from SE network sent to Stack Overflow Labs to sponsor Gen AI SE? All of this is so confusing to me.

Comment: It's a "Look at all the AI stuff we're doing!" campaign to attract new business. corporate-aligned things don't necessarily get announced to the public community directly (see "Teams for Communities")

Comment: Pretty sure this is the idea mentioned in [AI Tool example 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388893/323179).

Comment: @KevinB You mean *[Stack Overflow for Teams Communities](https://stackoverflow.co/company/press/archive/introducing-teams-communities)*?

Comment: @RandomPerson yes.

Comment: Honestly, when I received the email notification I thought it was a phishing attempt. The sender address was @stackoverflow.*email* and the web page is stackoverflow.*co*

Comment: @SapuSeven See MSO: [New official secondary domain: stackoverflow.co](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415962)

Comment: At least it provides a nice place for StackOverflow's potential customers to view all their genAI failures. Much better than forcing them to search though MSO and MSE looking for interesting ideas to avoid in their own experiments with AI. A valuable community service to the developers of the world.

Comment: I speculate that the current GenAI sponsorship is a temporary placeholder, and Stack Exchange are hoping some big name will see the WeAreDevelopers talk and offer e.g. server usage or free API calls, in return for exposure.  I note this all coincides with [Stack Exchange unilaterally declaring jailbreaking off-topic](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/83/26) which may be to avoid deterring potential advertisers.

Comment: The last edit should be rolled back and post a follow up question asking about the sponsorship of GenAI SE.

Answer (score 18):

We did not announce it on Meta SE or Meta SO.

It was released on June 13, 2023.

The purpose is to have a central hub to share our experiments, demos, insights, and news - across all Stack Overflow products. We plan to continually add to this site as we experiment and release new solutions.

We announced Stack Overflow Labs in conjunction with our Developer Survey release. It's on the [Dev Survey results site](https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2023/) and in the two blog posts we wrote about the Dev Survey ([results blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/06/13/developer-survey-results-are-in/) and [AI-focused blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/06/14/hype-or-not-developers-have-something-to-say-about-ai/)).

Comment: Are the "experiments, demos, insights, and news" only AI-specific?

Comment: Labs will be a place for the experiments we're doing, not just AI-specific ones.

Comment: Any particular reason why I can't sign up for news from Labs using a Gmail email address? Since it includes "all Stack Overflow products", that should include the public Q&A across the whole SE network in addition to Stack Overflow. Unless you're going to make a commitment to announce things here on Meta SE, everyone should be able to get news from Labs.

Comment: @ThomasOwens - we originally had an error with gmail addresses but we resolved it yesterday. Update: Confirmed the bug is back - I was able to replicate the error and have flagged it to be fixed.

Comment: @JC007B OK. I tried today after I saw this question and it didn't work. Still doesn't work now - just says "please use your work email address".

Comment: "We did not announce it on Meta SE or Meta SO" - that's obvious. The question is why. Do you consider the labs to be too minor so people should just find out by chance about it? Do you consider **us**, the community, unworthy to get such updates? Because sadly, that's how it looks like. But kudos for the new site.

Comment: @ThomasOwens - bug should be fixed. Let us know if you still have a problem.

Comment: @JC007B Confirmed - it works. No error messages and I received the confirmation email.

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack Probably because we are not the intended audience for that site. Everything announced there has been separately announced here or on the SO blog. So far it's just a repackaging of things that have already been shared with the community, just written in a way apparently designed to look good for the company.

Comment: I second the question: why wasn't it announced here on Meta?

Comment: Is SO Labs also a sponsor for sites in the SE network? Or is the sponsorship too, specific for AI sites only? @JC007B

Comment: @RandomPerson-onstrike: Just GenAI Stack Exchange at the moment.

Comment: @V2Blast Feel free to edit the answer or post a new answer.

Answer (score 5):

This addresses the first part of the question in OP title: "What is Stack Overflow Labs?" and the question

> What's the purpose of this new webpage?

From a comment at JC007B's answer:

> Labs will be a place for the experiments we're doing, not just AI-specific ones.

Right now (23-June-2023), however, it is only show-casing AI-related experiments.

[image: Screenshot of SO Labs page, showing AI related projects in various stages of completion, from 23-june-2023]

Comment: I'm not really sure how this answers my question. I think it would be better to post this as a comment under JC007B's post.

Comment: @Random It is addressed to this part of the question: "What's the purpose of this new webpage?", differently than JC's answer. "Across all SO products", JC says, but many of them are omitted on Labs. Only AI-related projects are mentioned there.

Comment: it also seems to be quite selective in which blog posts it shares, in that it happily includes blog and news posts that are supportive of AI and not all necessarily related to experiments, while leaving out similar AI related blog posts that aren't. ;)