# Use AI like ChatGPT to find duplicate questions

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, ai-tools

I know ChatGPT is banned on Stack Exchange. But could an AI tool be used in automation? I mean most of the time I try to find if my question is a duplicate or not before asking the question, and I see a lot of results in the list. But it takes a long time to check which are the most relevant.

It would be helpful for us (especially beginners) if AI could use the Stack Exchange site questions and answers' data to find the most relevant answer to that question before asking. It will definitely prevent duplicate questions being posted.

I'm not an expert so please don't ask me how can it be achieved, that's the engineer's job, I'm just making a request.

Comment: @ChatGPTStan and how is this related to the question? It is a specific feature request, the labs offer nothing related to it.

Comment: Anyway, a related discussion is: [How could AI be used to augment curation tooling?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389744/how-could-ai-be-used-to-augment-curation-tooling)

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard Hey wait. https://stackoverflow.co/labs/search/ is exactly what I want. It's not working now on the Stack Exchange sites. I hope it will be implemented in the near future.

Comment: A while back, I tried to come up with prompts for Bing Chat that would do this (basically, come up with search queries to find duplicates for a given question, run those queries, and give links to likely duplicates).  It ... sort of worked, although I had problems getting it to consistently obey my instructions, likely related to Microsoft's (fairly successful) attempts to keep it from producing...let's say, non-brand-safe content.  Probably one could get decent results with the fuller control you'd get from using the actual API, assuming you've got the ability to search programmatically.

Comment: Just running a web search has worked great for me. Why must we GPT everything?

Comment: Because it saves time. It's time effecient. It's simple as that.

Comment: @LeviAckerman Not in my experience. I waste enough hours battling hallucinations, trying to coax sense out of LLMs. Typing the right thing into DDG gets me a reasonable answer instantly, and if it's not the right thing, I can work with it sensibly to adjust. I'm not sure how waiting around for a loading spinner to spew a stream of probabalistic nonsense speeds anything up. Granted, the existing SO search functionality isn't great, but search engines have solved that problem, and SO could fix it with dumb technology the same way if they wanted to.

Comment: It will be an OPTION feature. If you don't want to use, don't use it. I'm not saying that AI will write its own answer. I'm just saying that it will help you find the most relevant answer to your question.

Comment: @LeviAckerman I don't think making it optional makes it OK--the company still wastes time and money developing it that should be spent on more pressing initiatives, it'll probably cause just as many problems as it solves, and the initiative will probably be used for manipulative/misleading marketing campaigns and to push AI initiatives that are more insidious. If it ain't broke, don't fix it. If there's an effective, cheap, dumb solution to a problem, the right decision is to use that rather than throw neural networks at it. The main reason people want overly complex solutions is hype.

Comment: @ggorlen May be it's not a good feature for you. But it's great feature for beginners. It'll help beginners to avoid asking duplicate questions. Also, it'll help their time. Not all are so minded. We're not fixing anything here. We're improving something. I'm not doing any AI marketing campaigns. It's just based on problem and solution. That's it. No need to involve politics of marketing in this. It's just to improve user experience and also to avoid duplicate answers.

Comment: @LeviAckerman all of your responses are purely anecdotal. You take it for granted that AI is great, has no problems, simply adds value and is apolitical. None of these things are for granted--if you've been using it, witnessing the totally incorrect answers GPT has flooded the site with, following the mod strike or watched how other AI proposals went down, or merely checked the downvotes on this question, you'd question your assumptions a bit more critically. It's a resource-intensive, expensive, frequently incorrect, highly controversial dumpster fire technology, from what I've seen.

Comment: @LeviAckerman Have you seen [Preview of Search and Question-Asking Powered by GenAI](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425766/preview-of-search-and-question-asking-powered-by-genai) which predates your proposal? It's pretty clear that the company doesn't really care about fixing search and duplicates, or they'd have done it in innumerable other ways prior to GPT. But once GPT shows up, all of a sudden the company is scrambling to find use cases for it, even for things they ostensibly didn't care about enough to fix prior to GPT.

Comment: @LeviAckerman Here's another: [AI/ML Tool examples part 2 - Extracting questions from Slack transcripts and finding similar/duplicate SO for Teams questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388893/ai-ml-tool-examples-part-2-extracting-questions-from-slack-transcripts-and-fin). I'm not the only one accusing SE of prioritizing speculative hype technology they want to market over proven, simple solutions.

Comment: Read my original question again. I didn't say anywhere about "ai summarization". "It's pretty clear that the company doesn't really care about fixing search and duplicates"... wait, what? Did you mean SE company? If yes, how is this attitude supposed to improve UX? Anyways, why can't we just vote for the feature - where all users could vote, not only just moderators or high reputations users.

Comment: @LeviAckerman That's correct, SE has prioritized marketing hype over improving functionality and listening to the community for years, to the detriment of the site. I don't see the benefit in letting people who have no experience or history using the site vote on which features get implemented. From the top link: "Ultimately, this updated search experience should result in fewer duplicate posts on Stack Overflow, provide a supportive onboarding of users through guided question-asking, and overall better quality of questions being asked on Stack Overflow."

Comment: @LeviAckerman If you're not asking for AI-based search and duplicate suggestions, what are you suggesting?

Comment: @ggorlen My suggestion is simple. Without feature -->> When I search for a question on SE websites, I see a tons of questions, how am I supposed to read of all those questions? Sometimes, when I post a questions, it turns out that it is a duplicate question. With feature -->> I'll enable the feature and will explain the problem to AI. Now instead of generating its own answer, it'll provide me the most relevant answers (from SE database). Why? Because AI can understand the "context". While simple search functionality doesn't have this feature i.e. to understand the context.

Comment: @LeviAckerman GPT doesn't _understand_ anything. It hallucinates wildly and has been shown to be totally unfit for all other uses it's been suggested for SE. During our discussion, I've been using it unsuccessfully to fix a simple failing test in a legacy project, with no luck. It gives the wrong answer and can't fix it no matter how I prompt it. I've closed hundreds of posts as duplicates and have been using traditional search engines alongside SE for half a decade. This approach is so effective, I've never had to ask a question on SE, and I started using the network as a complete novice.

Comment: @LeviAckerman I'm not asking you to read all questions, I'm asking you to choose worthwhile search terms, then iterate with a non-hallucinating search engine when and if the results aren't what you expect. Give it a try, then compare it to your favorite GPT. I can guarantee you the traditional approach will work better, save the occasional lucky GPT hit. if you can't manage to get traditional search working, I'm sorry, but GPTs are still a waste of time for SE to be exploring. They're only useful for appeasing the marketing team, board, and GPT spammers trying to rep farm. Net negative impact.

Comment: @ggorlen It hallucinates wildly only if the provided database is incorrect. I don't think SE database is of bad quality information. And yes, it doesn't understand the context in a traditional sense, but at least, it "seems" it understand the context thanks to advancement in AI. Plus, how do a beginner know that they are choosing worthwhile search terms or not? I said it earlier too that it may not be a great feature for YOU or for other minded people. But, it's a great way to avoid duplicate answers asked by beginners.

Comment: Also, I don't rely on simple gpt answers. I use browser extensions to access the internet so that gpt could provide me the best latest answers with proof.

Comment: @LeviAckerman Hallucinations will occur regardless of the underlying data quality, with hallucinated proof. As I mentioned before, basic searching served me just fine even when I was a beginner (and I still _am_ a beginner in many areas of interest). I don't think GPTs serve beginners well--it takes a good deal of experience to deal with lies.  SE investing further into GPTs is a waste of resources. I don't see that you're involved in Stack Overflow, so you may not be aware of the chaos GPTs have unleashed there. We're going in circles and I think I'll let the votes speak for themselves.

Comment: I mentioned you earlier that in this feature we will not let AI generate its own answers. Rather, it'll help beginners (just like me, and some others who are curious to find answers but don't have expertise to do a well research) to find the most relevant answer on SE to avoid asking duplicate questions. So hallucinations, lies, etc is not issue because there's no AI generated content. Plus, AI could also be used to avoid asking off-topic questions, but that's a different story in this discussion.

Answer (score -9):

Stack Overflow has announced that it will be using AI. One of these announcements was about OverflowAI (see [Announcing OverflowAI](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/07/27/announcing-overflowai/)). This announcement points to
Stack Overflow Labs / OverflowAI? -> https://stackoverflow.co/labs.

From this site the article that looks to be closely related to your "feature-request" is https://stackoverflow.co/labs/search.

---

Don't be surprised by the downvotes on [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)s. Post having this tag might get downvotes, meaning disagreement.

---

Related

- [New blog post from our CEO Prashanth: Community is the future of AI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388401/1395520)
- [Call for volunteer reviewers for an updated search experience: OverflowAI Search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426036)

Comment: You're really getting benefits of +1 = -5. Anyways, it will be good to see the AI used on the Stack Exchange website. But ChatGPT is banned here and so is an AI, right? So how did they announce that it will be using AI?

Comment: I think that you might misunderstood the ChatGPT ban. Each site might have a policy about posting content created by using generative AI tools. See [Is there a list of ChatGPT or other AI-related discussions and policies for our sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384922/1395520). The general use of ChatGPT is not banned. As a rule of thumb, don't post ChatGPT responses as answers.