# Should we clean up our AI-related tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

We have the following tags:

- [chatgpt](/questions/tagged/chatgpt)
- [ai-tools](/questions/tagged/ai-tools)
- [generative-ai](/questions/tagged/generative-ai) (synonym of [gen-ai](/questions/tagged/gen-ai)) (this is different from [prompt-design-site](/questions/tagged/prompt-design-site))
- [overflowai](/questions/tagged/overflowai)
- <s>[artificial-intelligence](/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence)</s><sup>1</sup>
- [robots](/questions/tagged/robots) (despite the tag wiki, this is being used on AI-related questions)

With the possible exception of OverflowAI, these tags are... somewhat ambiguous, and some are, to an extent, redundant.

What (if anything) should be done to clean up these tags?

---

Notes

**1** : Cleaned up. Ref. [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393408/).

Comment: I think that you should add more details about each tag. In the meantime, I think that it's not necessary to do anything on most of these, with the exception of [tag:robots] as apparently it was misused on some questions according to what you mentioned.

Comment: I have removed [tag:robots] from some recent questions were it was misused based on the tag usage guidance.

Answer (score 8):

Yes it's a bit of a mess at the moment, but there are some distinct concepts that should remain separate.
Having said that, there are only about 130 questions with any of these tags, and I certainly think we can tidy up a little.

---

For a start, the tag [artificial-intelligence](/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence) is just too vague.  Fortunately, there are only 2 question with this and they can just be retagged.*

The tag [robots](/questions/tagged/robots) (synonym: [bots](/questions/tagged/bots)) should be used for bots such as the Community Bot, Smoke Detector, chat bots, etc.  The tag wiki should be improved to list some of these examples.
If there are questions with this tag that aren't about these things then they should be retagged.
(Though personally I think [bots](/questions/tagged/bots) should be the target tag and [robots](/questions/tagged/robots) should be the synonym.)

ChatGPT (where GPT stands for Generative Pre-trained Transformer) is just a one particular brand/model of generative AI.  There are other models that basically do the same sort of thing and I can't see the point in brand distinct tags.  The [chatgpt](/questions/tagged/chatgpt) tag and the various other brands should be made synonyms of the general [generative-ai](/questions/tagged/generative-ai).

I don't know enough about [overflowai](/questions/tagged/overflowai) to say much about it, but as I understand it, it will use various [ai-tools](/questions/tagged/ai-tools) but it's very much supposed to be its own thing.

---

* For reference, I took the liberty of retagging those questions myself: ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392661/are-moderators-now-allowed-to-delete-chatgpt-generated-posts), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392563/use-ai-like-chatgpt-to-find-duplicate-questions)).

Comment: I disagree with making [tag:chatgpt] synonym of anything mentioned in the question and on this answer for while. This might deserve it's own post.

Comment: @Rubén What (other than prevalence) makes ChatGPT different from the other generative AI chatbots?

Comment: That discussion deserves its post. Please take it as a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The tag [generative-ai](/questions/tagged/generative-ai) has no tag wiki. It only has four questions. Generative AI is a topic that could inspire questions to many audiences of the Stack Exchange sites.

I have not seen tags and questions for Google Bard, Microsoft Bing ChatGPT, or other generative artificial intelligence services, API, platforms or related.

About [gen-ai](/questions/tagged/gen-ai)

Just in case someone argues that there is a site called GenAI, there are a few tags that are specific sites like [stack-oferflow](/questions/tagged/stack-oferflow), [serverfault](/questions/tagged/serverfault), among a few others, but those are legacy tags from times before [stackexchange-2.0](/questions/tagged/stackexchange-2.0). Any questions about GenAI Stack Exchange should be posted on the corresponding per-site meta, and questions about the process should be tagged [prompt-design-site](/questions/tagged/prompt-design-site).

Conclusion

The efforts around a tag cleanup touching [generative-ai](/questions/tagged/generative-ai) first require working on the tag wiki, prioritizing writing good usage guidance. Without this, I'm not convinced it would be made the main tag on a synonym relationship other than something that looks to be an abbreviation like [gen-ai](/questions/tagged/gen-ai).

Answer (score 1):

[robots](/questions/tagged/robots)

If we want this tag solely used for chatbots / bots to create and modify content on Stack Exchange realms, we must add it to the tag list on the question [chatbot](/questions/tagged/chatbot).

- [robots](/questions/tagged/robots) hast 62 questions
- [chatbot](/questions/tagged/chatbot) has 26 questions

I have not yet reviewed the questions tagged [chatbot](/questions/tagged/chatbot), but the term *chatbot* is commonly used to mean many things, including things related to the generative AI.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding [overflowai](/questions/tagged/overflowai), it looks like [stack-overflow-labs](/questions/tagged/stack-overflow-labs) and [ai-tools](/questions/tagged/ai-tools) are related.

- **OverflowAI** is a *marketing* artifact featured by Prashanth, the Stack Overflow CEO. Ref. [Announcing OverflowAI](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/07/27/announcing-overflowai/).
- **Labs** is another *marketing* artifact linked to the Stack Overflow brand. It has a microsite, and its URL is https://stackoverflow.co/labs/.

I suggest making them synonyms, making [ai-tools](/questions/tagged/ai-tools) the main tag as the brands might be abandoned sooner than the "ai" and "tools" terms, and while they are still in use, the contact related to these marketing campaigns should be done directly with the marketing and sales team ( the community managers handling Instagram, Twitter --now rebranded as X-- and other social networking channels deals with other platforms, community participation rules, not with Meta Stack Exchange rules and workings, if I have understood correctly).

So, the direction of the suggested synonyms are:

- [overflowai](/questions/tagged/overflowai) -> [ai-tools](/questions/tagged/ai-tools)
- [stack-overflow-labs](/questions/tagged/stack-overflow-labs) -> [ai-tools](/questions/tagged/ai-tools)

Answer (score 0):

[chatgpt](/questions/tagged/chatgpt) has 51 questions, several of them having thousands of views and many answers. It has 33 watchers. Because of the participation and interest around this tag, I strongly recommend discussing the clean-up on a specific question.

For the general public *chatgpt* is a generic name that refers to many things, not only the OpenAI product launched on November 30, 2022. Historically, this happened to many products, i.e., *kleenex* is commonly used as a generic name by specific populations for [facial tissue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facial_tissue) in several countries.

The synonymous feature might help handle some issues that might emerge around a clean-up project *chatgpt*, but not all.