# Does the new "Do large language models know what they are talking about?" post say that GenAI is bad?

Tags: discussion, blog

The newest blog post on the Stack Overflow blog is titled ["Do large language models know what they are talking about?"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/07/03/do-large-language-models-know-what-they-are-talking-about/). My reading of this post is that Generative AI is unreliable.

> I used one for this article to get information about the schools of epistemology and talk out some other ideas. It’s hard to say if the information it gave was actionable; it gave me fruitful avenues to go down for human-created knowledge, but I wouldn’t trust it to get everything right.

and

> Treating AI-generated information as purely actionable might be the biggest danger of LLMs, especially as more and more web content gets generated by GPT and others: we’ll be awash in information that no one understands. The original knowledge will have been vacuumed up by deep learning models, processed into vectors, and spat out as statistically accurate answers.  We’re already in a golden age of misinformation as anyone can use their sites to publish anything that they please, true or otherwise, and none of it gets vetted. Imagine when the material doesn’t even have to pass through a human editor.

---

Is this unreliable message the one that I should be taking away from this post? Assuming that it is, this conflicts with a lot of the recent GenAI pushes that have been stated by other representatives of Stack Exchange. Additionally, if this is the take away that Stack Exchange is presenting, why are we making such a massive push for GenAI on the network?

Comment: "this conflicts with a lot of the recent GenAI pushes that have been stated by other representatives of Stack Exchange" Could maybe some examples be given where other company officially state that GenAI is reliable or something similar? I'm not exactly sure I know what you mean there.

Comment: "why are we making such a massive push for GenAI on the network?" Maybe there are other advantages. The blog entry probably also said a few positive things about AI.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution Sure. [Network policy on moderating AI content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389583/186281) / [Formatting assistant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425162/189134) / [Title drafting assistant](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389262/186281) / [Post from the CEO announcing layoffs and focus on AI/ML offerings](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/05/10/a-message-from-prashanth-chandrasekar-ceo-stack-overflow/) / ["Community is the future of AI blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/04/17/community-is-the-future-of-ai/)

Comment: Yes, but where do they say that GenAI is reliable? Just look at the formatting assistant post "We realize from your responses that there are a lot of things that can be improved..." doesn't sound that positive. My impression is that the company is optimistic but not uncritical about the potential use of AI.

Comment: I mean... one doesn't layoff and reallocate a large percentage of staff and refocus all teams on AI projects without believing that said projects are great investments... They don't need to literally say it for their actions to speak it.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, but great investments doesn't mean that the method is flawless. Maybe they only expect it to become superior in the future not now or they think that the usefulness still outweighs the issues or they think there is no alternative really despite the drawbacks. I'm not totally convinced that they are contradicting themselves. We are interested in it and it's not reliable can both be true and it's not reliable doesn't equal it's bad.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution has anyone claimed it was flawless, or that the company claimed it was flawless? The argument is the company felt it worth going down this path at the detriment of all other work that the community needs done. Thus far, all of the experiments have produced questionable results and the company has gone from presenting overwhelmingly positive AI blog posts to two in a row questioning it's usefulness/developer sentiment. (neither of which have been added to [/labs/](https://stackoverflow.co/labs/))

Comment: bad for/at what? bad for the SE community/network/knowledgebase? bad at giving accurate and truthful information?

Answer (score 19):

I don't interpret it as saying "GenAI is bad".  It's saying the kinda obvious thing - "GenAI needs you to validate its output."

I would agree with you that this conflicts with the message that the company is pushing, in that GenAI can do a lot of cool things.  However, if we're just blindly trusting it, this can be highly problematic.

...I dunno why they'd publish this piece, but it *is* the same blog with a history of problematic posts, so...

Comment: Indeed, it might only prove that they vet neither AI results nor blog posts.

Comment: @tripleee:  I mean we know about the latter.  Extensively. Jury's out on the former.

Answer (score 5):

From what I can tell, the author of the blog post isn't in the decision-making part of Stack Exchange and only runs the editorial for the SO blog. It looks like the blog is independent of SE management, and is meant to give "Essays, opinions, and advice on the act of computer programming from Stack Overflow." Currently, LLMs *are* largely unreliable, and it wouldn't make much sense to say that they are even if the company is pushing GenAI technology.

Honestly, I don't know why they even chose to write about LLMs, as the message they are sending is contradictory to their AI policies. It may be due to lack of oversight as others have pointed out.

Comment: What is "lack of oversight"? Being double negative, it might mean the opposite, but don't think that's what you meant.

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack:  "Oversight" = "supervision."  "Lack of oversight"= "Lack of supervision" = management of stack overflow isn't paying attnetion to what's being done in their name on their blog.

Comment: @JRE yes, that is what I meant.