# What happened to the LLM-based title drafting tool?

Tags: support, title

A few months ago, I saw some blogs in the community about the title drafting assistant:
[this blog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388492/an-example-of-a-generative-ai-tool-suggesting-better-question-titles) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389262/ai-ml-tool-examples-part-3-title-drafting-assistant).

I've noticed that the community has recently been providing AI-related services, including search. So has there been any recent progress or discussion on the title?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It pretty much went nowhere.  Corporate introduced the assistant for a trial period, performed the laziest possible quantitative analysis, obtained inconclusive results, then disabled the tool, never to speak of it again.

Details: [Conclusions from title-drafting and question-content assistance experiments conducted by Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425525/)